# Can a Hermitian operator on a tensor product space be represented as a sum of tensor products of Hermitian operators?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, quantum-mechanics

Consider a Hilbert space (or just a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$), which is a tensor product of several smaller Hilbert spaces:
$$
H = H_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes H_n,
$$
and let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hermitian operator on $H$.

Can $\mathcal{H}$ always be represented as a sum of tensor products of *Hermitian* operators on the smaller Hilbert spaces?
i.e. can we write
$$
\mathcal{H} = \sum_i \mathcal{H}^{(1)}_i \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{H}^{(n)}_i,
$$
where $\mathcal{H}^{(k)}_i$ is a Hermitian operator on $H_k$?

I came up with this question in the context of Quantum Mechanics. I would expect that a Hamiltonian of a composite system can be represented as a sum of Hamiltonians, where each one is a tensor product of Hamiltonians of the smaller systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at least for finite dimensional vector spaces. First, I'll show you for two vector spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ and you can proceed by induction. Use the fact that any linear operator can be represented as a sum of tensor product of *linear* operators, and if $H$ is Hermitian then $\frac{H + H^\dagger}{2} = H$. That is, 
$$H = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^m A_i \otimes B_i + A_i^\dagger \otimes B_i^\dagger}{2}$$
for linear operators $A_i :H_1 \to H_1$ and $B_i:H_2 \to H_2$. Now 
$$ H = \sum_{i = 1}^m \left(\frac{A_i + A_i^\dagger}{2}\right) \otimes \left(\frac{B_i + B_i^\dagger}{2}\right) - \sum_{i = 1}^m \left(\frac{A_i - A_i^\dagger}{2i}\right) \otimes \left(\frac{B_i - B_i^\dagger}{2i}\right),$$
and each term is a tensor product of Hermitian operators.